# Unable to read memory for HWND in Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to figure out how to close an application (i.e. Mozilla Firefox) sing its HWND. But when I do something like this:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow("MozillaWindowClass", 0);
DestroyWindow(hwnd);
```

Visual Studio's debugger tells me that `hwnd` is unused - unable to read memory and nothing happens to Firefox. I was wondering what I'm doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you can safely close an application by simply annihilating one of its windows? Why do you want to do this? What is your goal? Kinda looks suspicious, to me.

Comment: After you actually get a handle to the window, Send WM_CLOSE message.

Comment: Don't discard the only option that actually does have a chance of working reliably: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: `HWND` is an opaque type. The value is merely a handle; there is no memory to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says:

> A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a
>   different thread.

You could try using [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send a [WM_CLOSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to the application.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have no idea why SendMessage wasn't working earlier.